# Spectrum Analyzer for line-in?

Tags: c#, winforms, audio

I'm looking for a small control (and the code behind that analizes) that shows me the incoming sound of my line-in/microphone.

I'm using winforms with c# and the control might if possible fit my toolbar.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the WPF demo project that comes with [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com) that shows a very basic spectrum analyser implementation. You would need to rework the graphics for WinForms though.

Comment: seems like just sound-out module :(
and don't have a winforms variant?